# How to access Template element and populate Model data in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to create a template and want to have four html div elements in it. Now in my views file I want to populate different data into these four template elements. Below is what I intend to achieve.

Html File:

```
<script id = "four-child-template">
<div id = "one> 
<div id = "two">
<div id = "three">
<div id = "four">
</script>
```

View File:

```
var widgetdata = new widgetdata.chart({});

  var myChartView4 = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function()
    {
       // I want to put four different data coming from model to the template div elements
// need help here. how to inject different values coming from models to corresponding div tags. 
$(this.el).html(this.model.attributes.incThisYear[this.model.attributes.incThisYear.length-1]); 
    },
    initialize: function() 
    {
     this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // registering on change of model
    }
  });
  new myChartView4({
    el: '#four-child-template',
    model: widgetdata 
  });
```

ATTEMPT 1 for Solution:

```
<body>
  <div id="divForRender"></div>
</body>

 <script id = "four-child-template">
 <div id="one"><%= j.attr1 %></div>
</script>

// WORKING for one ttop bar
var widgetdata = new chartmodel.chart({});

  var myChartView4 = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#four-child-template').html()),
   render: function()
    {


       var j = {}; // can use model.toJSON() but if you only want specific attributes then just assign as needed
        j.attr1 = "hello" ;
           $(this.el).html(this.template(j)); 
    },
    initialize: function() 
    {
     this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // registering on change of model
    }
  });

var t = new myChartView4({
    el: '#divForRender',
    model: widgetdata 
  });
t.render();
```

ERROR: VM6554:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the view is rendered, it will inject the html into divForRender.

```
<body>
  <div id="divForRender"></div>
</body>
```

Setup the template assuming then type of JSON data that can be expected.

```
<script id = "four-child-template">
 <div id="one"><%= attr1 %></div>
 <div id="two"><%= attr2 %></div>
 <div id="three"><%= attr3 %></div>
 <div id="four"><%= attr4 %></div>
</script>

var widgetdata = new widgetdata.chart({});
```

View Setup

```
var myChartView4 = Backbone.View.extend({
    /* Let the template in the view point to the above defined template id. */
    template: _.template($('#four-child-template').html()),
    render: function()
    {   
        /* Grab the relevant parts of the model and create object to pass to template. */
        var j = {}; // can use model.toJSON() but if you only want specific attributes then just assign as needed
        j.attr1 = this.model.get('myAttribute1');
        j.attr2 = this.model.get('myAttribute2');
        j.attr3 = this.model.get('myAttribute3');
        j.attr4 = this.model.get('myAttribute4');

        $(this.el).html(this.template(j)); 
    },
    initialize: function() 
    {
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // registering on change of model
    }
});

var cv4 = new myChartView4({
    el: '#divForRender',
    model: widgetdata 
});

cv4.render();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I am getting one error when the debugger crosses the line   $(this.el).html(this.template(j)); . Error: says VM6382:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined. But we have already defined j then why the error is coming. Kindly help.

Comment: I have added the code snippet that I have tried (as per your suggestion) in the question. Kindly see once.

Comment: @Unbreakable if you want to use `j` in underscore template, the object you pass to templating function should be like `{j:''}`. The one you're passing is like `{attr1:"hello"} `

Comment: But I want to achieve something as mentioned in this solution provided by @bvoleti. Something like `var j = {};        j.attr1 = 'hello'; j.attr2 = 'world';  $(this.el).html(this.template(j));`

Comment: I am new and learning all this. Kindly bear with me. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong in this sentence `j.attr1 = 'hello';`

Comment: Can you kindly provide one sample.

Comment: @Unbreakable if you have that your template should be `<div id="one><%= attr1 %></div>` the template engine is complaining there is no `j` property in the object you gave it.

Comment: @T J That's what I typically do (using toJSON). Just thought explicitly using the attributes would help in this case.